# How to reference to an asset in a folder?

Tags: html

If i wanted to show an image onto the page that is in a folder, how would i tell the program to find the image in a folder? 
`<img id="TrafficLights" src="Red Light.png">`

Would i have to go /"asset folder name"/Red Light.png?

I have looked online for a simple answer (as i am very new to html) and i find confusing explanations to questions that arent what im looking for, please answer as straight forward as possible if you can!

I cannot find anything online with a simple answer, please help!

Thank you

Comment: Rename your image filenames so they contain no spaces, replace them with dashes.

Answer (score 0):

yes bro if your image is in folder then you have to declare in the src attribute of img tag

for ex `<img src="folder_name/image_name.png" alt="image" />`

Comment: Dashes would be better than using underscores for SEO